MSCA Fellowship in Italy: salary and position
What contract are MSCA fellows hired with in Italy?
I've read somewhere that after the fellowship you are then most likely hired with a Rtda position. I've also read however that these Rtda positions do not exist any longer in favour of Rtt. Does someone know the status on this?

Doesn't the fellowship imply you are paid through the fellowship, from some EU funding? The university in Italy is only hosting you, not hiring you.

I might be wrong but I am not sure it works like this. They way I understand this is that the University establishes a grant agreement and then a contract is established between the university and the researcher. An implicit reference to this appears here: https://www.uniroma1.it/sites/default/files/09_FACSIMILE_CONTRATTO_MARIE_CURIE.rtf
and most importantly here https://www.unive.it/pag/12206 where an explicit amount for research contributions is stated.

Here is another reference to how the grant is handled by a major italian university: https://www2.uniroma1.it/senatoaccademico/verbali/10.2_08_11_2022.pdf
